# How to identify which ActiveDelegate is TRUE in Microsoft Bot framework IForm?

Tags: botframework

I have two ActiveDelegate (S):

ActiveDelegate isFormFlow = (procReq) => procReq.UXExp == UserExperience.FormFlow;

ActiveDelegate isLUISFlow = (procReq) => procReq.UXExp == UserExperience.LUIS;

Now, in my POST method, I want to check whether FormFlow is active or LUIS and accordingly I will call the function.

```
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{                        
  if (activity != null)
  {
    // one of these will have an interface and process it
    switch (activity.GetActivityType())
    {
      case ActivityTypes.Message:
        if (isFormFlow is TRUE)
        {
          await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialogForm);
        }
        else if (isLUISFlow is TRUE)
        {
          await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialogLUIS);
        }
        break;

      case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
      case ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate:
      case ActivityTypes.Typing:
      case ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData:
      default:
        Trace.TraceError($"Unknown activity type ignored: {activity.GetActivityType()}");
        break;
    }
  }
  return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

Please help me how to identify which delegate is active. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.ActiveDelegate<T>` is used within a FormFlow `FormDialog<T>` to determine whether a particular step is active or not, given the current form state.  It's not typically used to pick from multiple root dialogs (which you generally should only have one root dialog).